# Difference between a const and non-const function in C++

Tags: c++

I have been reading a C++ book and found these two functions:

```
    int &Array::operator []( int subscript ) // first
        {
            //code

            return ptr[ subscript ]; 
         }

 int Array::operator[]( int subscript ) const //second
{
    //code

    return ptr[ subscript ]; // value return
}
```

The idea is to create an Array object and access some private members, for example:

```
Array myArray;
cout << myArray[ 2 ];
```

But I don't get the difference between those functions, basically because every time I type something like "cout << myArray[ 2 ]" the first function is called. So , when is the second function called? Does the second function work?

Comment: Hint: What about trying it with `const Array myArray`?

Comment: YES! That was it , thanks

Comment: How about making two functions void c(const Array&a);, and void v(Array& a); and see which fn gets called inside each one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're declaring a mutable `Array` instance, the first function is used.

You need a `const` instance in order for the second one to be used:

```
const Array myArray;

// As this is const, only the second function can work
cout << myArray[2];
```

If you read the function signatures carefully, the second one has `const` at the end which means it applies to `const` instances. Normally if no non-`const` version is defined, this is the one that will run, but as you've gone out of your way to make the other version, that's the one that's called.

The first function allows mutation because it returns a *reference* instead of a copy:

```
myArray[2] = 5;
```

Where that actually changes the array. The `const` version does not permit this, you get a temporary value instead.

Comment: I would actually make it return a const ref instead. With the OP's way it _appears_ to mutate, even though the change is immediately discarded.

Answer (score 0):

A **const** behind a a non-static function qualifies the **this** pointer in the function. Thus the member variables appear in this function can't be modified. 
[const-qualified member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) gives more details about that.